# Using Bootstrap-Select with Html Extensions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, html-helper, bootstrap-select

I am using a drop down list HTML HELPER to display a drop down list of items. I want to turn this into a format provided by Bootstrap-Select.

Will I be able to implement this format, and still be able to use the HTML Helper extension the same way?

Thanks

Comment: Answer: @Html.ListBox( etc etc ) , new {class = "selectpicker"} 

works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this kind of alternative ?

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/3/